# Working chrome extension popup has sporadic CSP errors with firebase

Tags: firebase, content-security-policy, firebase-analytics

Only after a certain amount of time does this error occur. But if remove the extension from chrome and re-add it, it won't happen for a while.
This only happens in the `popup.html` file for some reason.

The error:
Error:

```js
`BrowserPollConnection.ts:740` Refused to load the script 'https://fb-instance.firebaseio.com/.lp?start=t&ser=xx&cb=3&v=5&p=1:xxx' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.
```

[image]

There is nothing I can add or change to the manifest `content_security_policy`, and I believe that the popup is part of the `extension_pages`.
And again, this error only occurs after a certain time (or something else that I don't know of), and removing and re-adding the extension is the only way to "fix" the error.
This only happens since maybe a week, perhaps a chrome update (Now on: v104.0.5112.81)

So if I follow that `firebasio.com` url, there is some kind of firebase script that wants to execute from remote:

```js
function pLPCommand(c, a1, a2, a3, a4) {
parent.window["pLPCommand1"] && parent.window["pLPCommand1"](c, a1, a2, a3, a4);
}
function pRTLPCB(pN, data) {
parent.window["pRTLPCB1"] && parent.window["xxx"](pN, data);
}
         pLPCommand('start','123','abcd');
pRTLPCB(0,[{"t":"c","d":{"t":"h","d":{"ts":xxx,"v":"5","h":"fb-instance.firebaseio.com","s":"xxx"}}}]);
```

I know this is not even a critical script and is probably some sort of analytics, since the popup works fine before this... until it doesn't...

Manifest.json (MV3):

```json
  "content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'; script-src-elem 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://www.gstatic.com/ https://*.firebaseio.com https://*.firebasedatabase.app https://www.googleapis.com"
  },
```

And I don't want to re-write the whole popup so that it uses the `sandbox` CSP, and have to rewire it, and then I can't access the `chrome.window`, `chrome.tabs` etc, APIs and would have to forward the authentication etc. JUST to avoid a problem that is cause by what seems to be a non-critical script that the `firebase` library wants to execute for some reason.

And before the error occurs I don't see any requests to that `https://subdomain.firebaseio.com/.lp?start=t&ser=etcetc` url, and I'm not sure what triggers this to happen. And once it does, it will keep happening, until I remove the extension completely and re-add it, reloading does not work...

(Using: "firebase": "^9.6.3" atm)

## /Update

I've narrowed it down to the `onAuthStateChanged` part of my firebase code. So instead, I now send a message to the background page to get my `auth.uid` then I can just operate normally. (I just needed it for a query)

But it's odd, because I do the initial login/auth through the newtab/options page.
But I can still create firestore entries in the popup and I'm not even doing `firebase.initializeApp(config)` in the popup anywhere so I wonder how this 'sandboxed' script knows who I am, but this is a different question entirely...

Answer (score 2):

I also got stuck in this problem and spent a lot of time to solve it.

```js
localStorage.removeItem("firebase:previous_websocket_failure")
```

The SDK will set `firebase:previous_websocket_failure` to `true` in localStorage when the websocket connection is not available.

That's where the problem arises.

Comment: can confirm. adding localStorage.setItem("firebase:previous_websocket_failure", true) will cause the problem and this solution will fix it.

Comment: I could kiss you! This is exactly the problem I was facing, my extension was working one day, then the next day it stopped working with CSP errors being through, seemingly because Firebase reverted back to a fallback method of communication. Thank you for the insight!

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure why it's working from time to time, but from my understanding is not possible to add those urls to the CSP.
From the [Google Chrome Documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-migration/#content-security-policy)

> In addition, Manifest V3 disallows certain CSP modifications for extension_pages that were permitted in Manifest V2. The script-src, object-src, and worker-src directives may only have the following values:
> `self`, `none`, Any localhost source, (http://localhost, http://127.0.0.1, or any port on those domains)

Comment: I read that, but I find `extension_pages` really vague, and it never happens on newtab or options pages.. I've narrowed it down to the `onAuthStateChanged` part of my firebase code. So now I send a message to the background page to get my `auth.uid` then I can just operate normally. Which is odd, because I login through the newtab/options page. But I can still create firestore entries as if I'm authenticated. I'm not even doing `firebase.initializeApp(config)` in the popup, anywhere, but that is another question entirely..