I tried to connect firebase to my chrome extension but It didn't work
It showed this error:
Refused to load the script 'https://gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.9/firebase-app.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src-elem 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://www.gsataic.com https://*.firebaseio.com https://www.googleapis.com".
I build my chrome extension with manifest version 3,
Please help me !
I tried to add
"content_security_policy": {
"extension_pages": "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval' ; object-src 'self'; script-src-elem 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://www.gsataic.com https://*.firebaseio.com https://www.googleapis.com;"
}
to manifest.json but it still didn't work

I'm not sure how you're adding the Firebase SDK to your extension but, if it worked for a while and then stopped working, this may be the reason https://stackoverflow.com/q/73249719/1552587
